# DocuSign: listing Document Custom fields → Empty JSON response

Tags: docusignapi

When I execute a API GET call to get a list of Document Custom fields on my developers DocuSign account I get a empty JSON response where the status code is showing 200.

And when I'm looking at the documentation on DocuSign itself the response is also empty. Is there a reason for the empty response?

Answer (score 1):

[Tabs aren't the same as Document Custom Fields in API terms](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-trenches-tabs-and-custom-fields). Are you sure you're using Document Custom Fields?

If you're trying to pull tabs / form data, that would be a different call, such as GetEnvelope with `include=recipients,tabs`, ListTabs, or ListRecipients with `include=tabs=true`

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any Custom fields? DocuSign accounts don't come pre-provisioned with any custom fields. No custom fields = empty response with 200 OK. [Here's](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-trenches-tabs-and-custom-fields) a blog post from DocuSign which explains how these work. If you have created some but the response is still empty, then this would need to be investigated

Comment: Yes I have create a few custom fields but still an empty response. Where can I start with investigation around the situation?

Comment: You can open a case with DocuSign developer support here: https://developers.docusign.com/support/